# Como enviar uma variável do tipo array de objetos via AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Tenho o seguinte objeto:

```
var pessoas = [];

pessoas = {

  nome: "julio",
  sobrenome: "Henrique",
  idade: 18,
  amigos : ["Pedro", "João", "Isabella"]

}
```

Faço o envio do array amigos via ajax assim:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'retira_falsos_amigos.php',
    type: "post",
    data: { amigos: pessoas.amigos },

    complete: function (response) {
        $('#output').html(response.amigosVerdadeiros);
    },
    error: function () {
        $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
    },
});
```

e não resulta erro.

Porém, no meu código, **o array `amigos` vira um array de objetos** e, ao fazer a mesma requisição, resulta em erro.

quando ele vira um array de objetos fica assim:

```
itensAmigos[0] = {

  name: data[0][0],
  intervalo: intervalo,
  Start: Date.UTC(ano,mes,dia,hora,minuto),
  data: data[0][1],
  tooltip: {
     valueSuffix: " -"
  }

};

pessoas = {

  nome: "julio",
  sobrenome: "Henrique",
  idade: 18,
  amigos : itensAmigos

}
```

Este é o erro que aparece:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem o problema. Poderia colocar o trecho do código PHP onde você trata os dados recebidos e qual erro está aparecendo?

Comment: complementei minha pergunta com o erro, porem o erro que aparece não faz sentido com meu código

Comment: encontrei a solução, se eu estava enviando um array() devo informar que a variável que vai levar os dados tbm é um array, daí a necessidade de por data: { 'amigos[]': pessoas.amigos }, entre aspas. depois disso nao da mais o erro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Envie seu objeto formatado completo e trate no php com json_decode().
Para enviar os dados use a função [JSON.stringify()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp) que vai convertê-lo em uma string.

```
$.ajax({
    url:'retira_falsos_amigos.php',
    type: "post",
    data: { dados: JSON.stringify(pessoas) },

    complete: function (response) {
        $('#output').html(response.amigosVerdadeiros);
    },
    error: function () {
        $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
    },
});
```

**retira_falsos_amigos.php**

```
$amigos = isset($_POST['dados']) ? $_POST['dados'] : null;
$objAmigos = json_decode($amigos);
foreach($objAmigos->amigos as $key=>$obj){
    echo "Amigo ".$key." - Nome: ".$obj."<br>";
}
```

> A resposta tem como base o exemplo dado na questão

Comment: poderia me mostrar como pegar as variaveis desse objeto no php com o json  json_decode().

Comment: Editei a resposta, se ficar confusa posso explicar melhor como funciona cada trecho

Comment: sim entendi, ficou joia! entretanto essa requisição da erro conforme mostrado na pergunta

Comment: O erro no final da pergunta não parece ser relacionada ao ajax, parece uma propriedade nao definida dentro do highstock.js linha 458, nao sei direito como essa biblioteca funciona, mas pode ter alguma coisa faltando no html que ela usa de referencia, um id, class ou até mesmo canvas.

Answer (score 1):

A primeira coisa é você definir a propriedade `dataType` do `ajax` como `json` para que você possa receber o retorno do PHP como um objeto.

Em vez de usar o `complete` do `ajax`, use o `success`. O `complete` sempre vai ser executado independente se ocorrer algum erro no processamento da requisição ou não, já o `success` apenas se tudo ocorrer corretamente.

Segue um exemplo funcional:

**index.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(function () {

                var pessoas = {
                    nome: "Julio",
                    sobrenome: "Henrique",
                    idade: 18,
                    amigos: ["Pedro", "João", "Isabella"]
                };

                function enviaFalsosAmigos() {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "retira_falsos_amigos.php",
                        type: "post",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: {amigos: pessoas.amigos},
                        success: function (response) {
                            var listaDeAmigosVerdadeiros = response.listaDeAmigosVerdadeiros;
                            for (var i = 0; i < listaDeAmigosVerdadeiros.length; i++) {
                                alert(listaDeAmigosVerdadeiros[i] + " é um amigo verdadeiro!");
                            }
                        },
                        complete: function () {
                            alert("A requisição foi finalizada.");
                        },
                        error: function (erro) {
                            alert("Ocorreu um erro ao processar a requisição.");
                        }
                    });
                }

                $("button").click(function (event) {
                    enviaFalsosAmigos();
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button>Clique para enviar os falsos amigos</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

**retira_falsos_amigos.php**

```
<?php
$listaDeAmigosFalsos = $_POST["amigos"];
$listaDeAmigos = ["Pedro", "João", "Isabella", "Diego"];

$listaDeAmigosVerdadeiros = array_diff($listaDeAmigos, $listaDeAmigosFalsos);

echo json_encode(["listaDeAmigosVerdadeiros" => array_values(listaDeAmigosVerdadeiros)]);
```

Answer (score -3):

O primeiro passo é definir qual o tipo da requisição na sua chamada ajax:

```
$.ajax({
url:'retira_falsos_amigos.php',
type: "post", // Defina aqui o tipo da requisição
data: { amigos: pessoas.amigos },

complete: function (response) {
    $('#output').html(response.amigosVerdadeiros);
},
error: function () {
    $('#output').html('Bummer: there was an error!');
},
```

});

Com isso o seu javascript vai fazer uma requisição do tipo post para o arquivo php retira_falsos_amigos.php.
e para pegar o seu array no php você deve usar a variável global $_POST['amigos']:

```
$amigos = isset($_POST['amigos']) ? $_POST['amigos'] : null;
```

Comment: oi thiago, editei a pergunta mostrando melhor qual erro ocasiona em qual situação. o array amigos, se torna um array de objetos e ai ocariona erro quando faço essa requisição, com ou sem a declaração de type

Comment: O  erro que acontece é no retorno do ajax? você está utilizando outros script além do jquery?

Comment: postei o que acontece na pergunta